# Is HTML, CSS remote debugging possible for Mobile and Tablets like Android , ipads?

Tags: html, css, ipad, mobile-website, remote-debugging

Is HTML, CSS remote bugging depossible for Mobile and Tablets like Android , iPads?

For example I want to use firebug on Ipad website, but from my desktop and firebug changes should be seen in iPad.

my question is not specifically to Firebug, if I can use Safari developer tools, IE 9 developer toolbar or similar tools which can edit live css, html on pages., it would be fine.

**Note:**

I already know about Firebug Lite. But my question is about remote debugging.

Mobile phones and tablets doesn't have Mouse so it's inconvenient to use Firebug lite on them.

Answer (score 1):

Remy Sharp has a couple of solutions, as he usually does.

Firebug Bookmarklet

http://remysharp.com/2007/03/13/firebug-in-ie-for-any-web-site/

JS Console remote debugging (jsconsole.com).

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSH392Gxaho

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can on iPads - I have used [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) in the past to debug a javascript problem I was having

Comment: What about iphone and android phone?

Comment: I haven't tested it on Android Phones nor iPhone's.

Answer (score 0):

Not on the actual device but you can get emulators for all those devices and run those emulators on your desktop.

That still doesn't allow you to run Firebug on the device but you can run Firebug in your desktop browser, fix the issues locally and then reload the page in the emulator to see if it works.

For Android, there is a mobile version of Firefox but I'm not sure if you can Firebug on it. Even if you can: The display size is very limited, so I don't think that it will be a pleasant experience.

Comment: may I ask you to have a look at a remote-debugging  related question here : tinyurl.com/ovglq92 ?

Answer (score 0):

For remote javascript debugging, checkout the Crossfire project:

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Crossfire

Answer (score 0):

remote debug
safari and chrome both have this function.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Safari's developer tool "Develop -> User Agent -> iPad / iPod / iPhone" and you can view the website on your desktop as it will look on these devices.

Comment: Does that setting do anything else besides manipulating the user agent?